# Does index works for LIKE statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table `(id, title)`, where `id` is PK. For a query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE "%stackoverflow%"`, I tried indexing `title` and fulltext indexing `title`. I used `EXPLAIN` to check if index works, and both don't work.

I am told index doesn't work for `LIKE "%...%"`. Is this the case?

Comment: Use `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

noup it wont work, however if your index is 'xxx%' it will work,

another thing is your MySQL Version is older than 5.6 your engine HAVE TO BE MyIsam or Aria, but it cannot be Innodb to have a text index